# Flask test_client is not restarted at setUp() of unittest.TestCase

Tags: unit-testing, flask, nose

I am writing a small REST service with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

```python
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['count']=0

@app.route("/count")
def get_count():
    app.config['count']+=1
    return str(app.config['count']-1)

@app.route("/reset")
def reset():
    app.config['count']=0
    return str(app.config['count'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Sequential calls to `/count` should return `0, 1, 2, ...`. Calling `/reset` should reset the counter.

In order to test it, I've followed the [flask and nose tutorial](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/12/05/flask-with-mock-and-nose/)::

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import flask_server as server
import unittest
from nose.tools import assert_equals

class TestUnitBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print "Setting up!"
        server.app.testing=True
        self.app = server.app.test_client()

    def test_count_is_zero_in_new_server(self):
        """/count should return 0 for a new server"""
        response       = self.app.get("/count")
        data, status   = response.data, response.status
        assert_equals(int(data), 0)
        print data, status

    def test_count_is_zero_in_new_server_again(self):
        """Asserts that the uptime response contains "boot" and "test" elements."""
        response       = self.app.get("/count")
        data, status   = response.data, response.status
        assert_equals(int(data), 0)
        print data, status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.run(argv=[__file__, '--with-doctest', '-v', '-s'])
```

The methods are identical, and I expect both of them to pass, but:

```
 $ nosetests -vs location_update_server/server/test_flask_server.py
/count should return 0 for a new server ... Setting up!
0 200 OK
ok
Asserts that the uptime response contains "boot" and "test" elements. ... Setting up!
FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: Asserts that the uptime response contains "boot" and "test" elements.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adam/vioozer/servers/location_update_server/server/test_flask_server.py", line 28, in test_count_is_zero_in_new_server_again
    assert_equals(int(data), 0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.025s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

**The `setUp` method was indeed called twice, but the server was created only once**. How can I set the test so that every call to `setUp()` would start a new server, with `counter=0`?

Comment: Does `TestUnit` subclass `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: @dim Yes. And setUp runs once for each test.

Comment: Is this counter that you mention in your example state that you keep in the test client or in the server? I think an example test that uses the counter might help understanding the problem better.

Comment: @Miguel updated my answer with full server and test code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new application for each test, so that each test starts sending request to a brand new server. By "application" I mean the instance of class `Flask`.

Unfortunately this is a non-trivial change. The basics are explained in the official documentation: [Application Factories](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/).

After you follow the instructions in the referenced page you will not be calling

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

in the global scope anymore, instead you will have a `create_app()` function that returns this `app` object. Each test can make its own then. Any requests you send into a brand new `app` object will be the first.

The tricky part about switching to an app factory is that once you move the `app` creation into a function you cannot use `app.route()` anymore to define your routes, since `app` is not defined in the global scope anymore. The solution is to use a blueprint that is attached to the application at run-time.

As a side note, the standard practice of calling the test client `self.app` like this:

```
self.app = server.app.test_client()
```

is pretty confusing. Now you have two `app` things. I prefer to call it client, since that is what it is:

```
self.client = server.app.test_client()
```

Lastly, note that your REST API is not really RESTful due to the dependency on order of calls and this undeterministic behavior is actually causing your problem. Your `/count` route is not really representing a resource, it is representing an action. `GET` requests should be read-only, changes to a resource should normally be issued with a `PUT` request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! On a sidenote, how would you store a global counter for a REST service?

Comment: @AdamMatan: I'm not sure what's your use case for needing a counter, but I would not give the client the ability to increment the counter directly, I would just count whatever events need to be counted in the server indirectly, based on what the client does. For example, if I wanted to count requests I would just add a `before_request` handler that increments an internal counter. If I need to expose the counter I would have a `stats` resource exposed as a `/stats` route that returns the current value.

Comment: For the unit test I would read the counter first, run the test, and then make sure the counter incremented the correct number of times. The test should not care that the counter starts from 0.